# Show lines which does not contain specific string on Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file on my Linux server with these characters:

```
  ID              DATA
MF00034657,12435464^DRogan^DPUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;M-DT_MAX_1;
MF00056578,12435464^DRogan^DPUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;PUM-DT_MAX_1234;UM-DT_MAX_123;
```

Now I need to filter the lines which do not contain "PUM-DT_MAX_1234" and save them in another file with the ID.

Like this:

```
MF00034657,M-DT_MAX_1
MF00056578,UM-DT_MAX_123
```

I use:

```
grep -v 'PUM-DT_MAX_1234' file > file.out
awk '!/PUM-DT_MAX_1234/' file > file.out
```

But it doesn’t work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: In the example you give you only have 2 lines, and both of them have the string you want to filter out on.  Perhaps you need to fix the formating of the examples if it's not supposed to have just 2 lines?

Comment: Try: awk '$0 !~ /PUM-DT_MAX_1234/' file > file.out

Comment: `sed '/PUM-DT_MAX_1234/d' file >file.out`

Comment: I'm confused by your terminology and inadequate example. Do you want to print the lines that DO contain PUM-DT_MAX_1234 or DO NOT contain it?

Comment: sorry, i need print the lines do not containt the pattern 'PUM-DT_MAX_1234' for example;           M-DT_MAX_1

Comment: But both lines of your sample input DO contain the string `PUM-DT_MAX_1234`. Edit your question to show a better example that includes both lines that do and do not contain that string.

Comment: Perhaps you ought to explain *how* `grep -v` and the other suggestions don't work. Example input *and* output, along with expected output and how it differs from the actual output might be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '1b
h;s/.*DRogan^D//;s/PUM-DT_MAX_1234;\{0,1\}//g;s/;$//;/./!d
H;g;s/,.*\n/,/' YourFile
```

- based on your sample

Concept:

- keep a copy of the line
- remove head and any "PUM" from the line. Check if something stay
- get back the header (from the buffered line) and reformat with the reduce line

Answer (score 37):

Use:

```sh
awk '$0 !~ /your_pattern/'
```

As [found](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-11) in the (probably) greatest [AWK documentation](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: This looks like code golf compared to the other solutions here. Thanks for the simplicity and elegance.

Answer (score 4):

I'll use an analogy of your problem with the command `ls` (because it is easy to implement), let's say I want to display all files that are not `mp4`, you do the following:

```
ls | awk '! /\.mp4/'
```

If you want to  go further with the options, I could be actually looking for a file that it ***does not*** contain the `mp4` extension and it ***does*** contain an specific string, e.g. `abc`:

```
ls | awk '! /\.mp4/ &&  /abc/'
```

This should be analogous and applicable to your purposes (or at least, not hard to implement).

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to remove any field containing "PUM-DT_MAX_1234" then you have to iterate over each field in your line:

```
awk -F "[;,]" -v OFS="," 'NR==1 { next; }; { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(!match($i,/.*PUM-DT_MAX_1234.*/) && length($i) > 0) { if (i==1) r=$i;  else r = r OFS $i }}; print r }' filter.txt
```

In a more readable view with comments:

- `-F "[;,]"` Set the field separator to be `;` or `,`
- `-v OFS=","` Set the output separator to be `,`
- `'NR==1 { next; };` `'` start of the AWK script. The rest is to skip the header of your file (if the record number is 1, stop and go to to the next line
- `{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {` Iterate over the number of fields (`NF`)
- `if(!match($i,/.*PUM-DT_MAX_1234.*/) && length($i) > 0) {` If the field is not null and don't match the text
- `if (i==1) r=$i;  else r = r OFS $i` concatenate the field to previous one (or just set it to the first field to avoid a leading `,` in the output)
- `print r }'` Once the loop ends, print the result of the previous concatenation, and end the AWK script with `'` for the shell
- `filter.txt` Last argument is the file name.

`OFS` is the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator, so you can change it by changing the variable on the command line.

Output from your example:

```
MF00034657,M-DT_MAX_1
MF00056578,UM-DT_MAX_123
```

Answer (score 0):

In [silgon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667233/show-lines-which-does-not-contain-specific-string-on-linux/45955293#45955293), the command worked after I removed the gap in '! /.mp4/'

- I wanted to remove "none" images from 'docker images' output, using [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```html
docker images | awk '!/\<none>/'
```

- I wanted to print the name and tag only from 'docker images' output, i.e., column 1 and 2 from an output excluding "none" images as well, using AWK:

```html
docker images | awk '!/\<none>/' | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

Comment: Had to include the command in html snippet as <none> was not displaying anything in code option

Comment: hey @Syed. It seems that the answer you put is mainly a question. Please remove it. In the meantime, (while you remove it) and for your reference  to your question: `docker rmi $(docker images | grep "<none>")` and `docker images | awk '!/<none>/ {print $1,$2}'`. Cheers!